# Why is my django template not outputting template variable object?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am having issues getting my template to output my `Post`objects, which represent a blog post. On my main index page my blog posts display just fine, and i have no problem loading the template variables. When a user clicks one of the archive dates, which represent an archive link to display posts from a certain day and month, the same index page is used but given a different set of posts to display, filtered by date.

**views.py**

```
def month(request, year, month):
    """Monthly archive."""
    posts = Post.objects.filter(created__year=year, created__month=month)

    d = dict(posts=posts, user=request.user, months=mkmonth_lst(), archive=True)
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', d)
```

**index.html**

```
{% for post in posts.object_list %}
        <div class="blogpost">
            <div class="blogpost-title"><h2>{{ post.title }}<h2></div>
            <div class="blogpost-meta"><h4>{{ post.created }}</h></div>
            <div class="blogpost-body">{{ post.body|linebreaks }}</div>
            <div class="blogpost-comments"><a href="{% url 'post' post.id %}">Comments</a></div>
        </div>          
        {% endfor %}
```

In the above month function, after retrieving the list of `Post` objects and counting them i can see they are being retrieved. The problem is the index page not outputting them.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template you should loop through `posts`, not `posts.object_list`.

Comment: Thankyou! that is weird, i was originally using `posts.object_list` to output my entire collection of posts, yet it didnt work when outputting the subset of posts.

Comment: Were you using [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/) in the other view, or using a class based view that does pagination?

Comment: Yes the other view uses pagination, but shares the template with `months`. The pagination still seems to work using just `posts`, is there a reason i read somewhere to use `posts.object_list`?

Comment: The [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view) doesn't loop through `object_list`, so I think it's fine to loop through `posts` if it works for you.